# Google App Scripts For New Google Sites Release

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites-2016

Google revamped their sites platform in November 2016, however there is no longer an option for writing Google Apps Scripts for it, as far as I'm aware. Has Google announced when they will incorporate this into their new sites platform? Any ideas?

Comment: If anyone knows, it be the ones who drink over here:  https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also look for this, but for now no prediction. We're just sure that Google Apps Script does not yet work with New Google Sites, as we see here on the official site: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/

Apps Script cannot currently access or modify New Google Sites:
[image]

Answer (score 8):

In case ppl are still looking, it's now possible to [embed apps on new google sites](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#embedding_a_web_app_in_new_sites)

**Embedding a web app in new Sites**

In order to embed a web app, it must first be deployed in the Google [apps script editor](https://script.google.com). You also need the Current web app URL from the 'Deploy as web app dialog' (make sure to get the one ending 'exec' one and not the one ending 'dev').

Or you can host an html page on, e.g. github; you'll then need that URL (whatever host you use, it must be https and host must allow iframing).

To embed a web app or url into a new Sites page, follow these steps:

Open the Sites page where you'd like to add the web app.

1. Select Insert > Embed URL.
2. Paste in the web app (or, e.g. github ) URL and then click ADD.

The web app appears in a frame in the page's preview.

When you publish the page, your site viewers may need to authorize the web app before it executes normally. Unauthorized web apps present authorization prompts to the user (you make these settings when you 'deploy as web app' if using a Google apps script).

Comment: I am having troubles following this procedure with my own script. I followed the procedure and embedded a Google App Script, which makes use of `setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)`. The page is correctly embedded if I open it, but cannot be displayed by other users (the javascript console shows a 405 error). In case it helps, the published web app is at 

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzTEtHuQvAjfc7GQ1q8Q8xhs2khs7kxus_PPjmOg7eVxrrb6XjX/exec

Comment: I've just tried embedding that URL on a test google site of mine and it seems to work:
Risultati — ,

Problema Punteggio
P1a: 0.0 (risposta non fornita)
P1b: 0.0 (risposta non fornita)
P1c: 0.0 (risposta non fornita)
P2a: 0.0 (risposta non fornita)
P2b: 0.0 (risposta non fornita)
P2c: 0.0 (risposta non fornita)
P3a: 0.0 (risposta non fornita)
P3b: 0.0 (risposta non fornita)
P3c: 0.0 (risposta non fornita)

Voto esame: 0


L'esame non è stato superato